# quisiera saber como simplificar lo que muestro acontinuacion

Tags: php, jquery

Quiero saber si se puede hacer mediante un `for` dentro del `if` o como se podría simplificar para hacerlo dinámico sin tener que meter yo las variables.

```
function pasarvaloresdensidad(){
    var numerobusqueda =$("input#numerobusqueda").val();// coje un valor numerico de un input
    // hacer un for con <= numerobusqueda y meter el resultado en un array que sacaremos  en el envio de datos de abajo 
    var textoBusqueda = $("#resultadoBusqueda1").val();
    var textoBusqueda1 = $("#resultadoBusqueda2").val();
    var textoBusqueda2 = $("#resultadoBusqueda3").val();
    var textoBusqueda3 = $("#resultadoBusqueda4").val();
    var textoBusqueda4 = $("#resultadoBusqueda5").val();
    var textoBusqueda5 = $("#resultadoBusqueda6").val();
    if (textoBusqueda !== "" || textoBusqueda1 !=="" || textoBusqueda2 !=="") {
        // intentar meter un for para recorrer el array de abajo el envio de la variables y hacer que numBusqueda sea cambiado el numero por la i del for y lo mismos para texto busqueda
        $.post("prueba.php", {numBusqueda: textoBusqueda,numBusqueda1: textoBusqueda1,numBusqueda2: textoBusqueda2,numBusqueda3: textoBusqueda3,numBusqueda4: textoBusqueda4,numBusqueda5: textoBusqueda5}, function(mensaje) {// buscar.php es la pagina donde instanciaremos la clase y haremos la busqueda
            //$("#resultadoBusqueda").html(mensaje);// mensaje es el que se va a retornar al hacer la busqueda en la funcion de la clase claculadora
            $('#total').html(mensaje);//.html para aññadir html a cualquier tipo de div parrafo o etiquetas que no sean de inputs   
        }); 
    } 
};
```

Comment: si colocas el html seria bueno asi podremos ayudarte de una mejor forma!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en vez de pasar 6 valores en el objeto, porque no pasas una array? He hecho un codigo un poco más simplificado, aqui lo tienes:

```js
function pasarvaloresdensidad() {
    var numerobusqueda = $("input#numerobusqueda").val(); // coje un valor numerico de un input
    var arrayConValores = [];
    var algunCampoLleno = false;
    for (let i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
        arrayConValores.push($("#resultadoBusqueda" + i).val());
        if ($("#resultadoBusqueda" + i).val() !== "") {
            algunCampoLleno = true;
        }
    }

    if (algunCampoLleno) {
        $.post("prueba.php", {
            arrayBusquedas: arrayConValores
        }, function (mensaje) {});
    }
}
```

Comment: se que alomejor no deberia de preguntar esto aqui  pero como e ha servido de muchicsima ayuda tu post quisiera preguntarte si me podrias ver este otro post  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/233984/quisiera-saber-como-simplificar-lo-que-muestro-acontinuacion-con-el-codigo-js?noredirect=1#comment434844_233984