# quisiera saber como simplificar lo que muestro acontinuacion con el codigo js

Tags: jquery

queria saber si se puediera simplificar esto mediante und for con arrays si es posible

```
function buscar() {
    var textoBusqueda = $("input#busqueda1").val();
    var porcentajequimico = $("input#porcentajequimico1").val();
    if (textoBusqueda !== "" && porcentajequimico !== 0) {
        $.post("buscar.php", {
            valorBusqueda: textoBusqueda
        }, function(mensaje) { // buscar.php es la pagina donde instanciaremos la clase y haremos la busqueda

            var total = porcentajequimico * mensaje;
            //$("#resultadoBusqueda").html(mensaje);// mensaje es el que se va a retornar al hacer la busqueda en la funcion de la clase claculadora
            $('#resultadoBusqueda1').val(total); //.val para añadir valores de texto o variables a un input 
        });
    } else {

        $('#resultadoBusqueda1').val('escriba quimico'); // resultado busqueda es el contenedor donde mostramos el mensaje que es lo que hemos buscado con la palabra o nos aha devuelto la busqueda
    };
    // 2 busqueda de los input
    var textoBusqueda1 = $("input#busqueda2").val();
    var porcentajequimico1 = $("input#porcentajequimico2").val();
    if (textoBusqueda1 !== "" && porcentajequimico1 !== 0) {
        $.post("buscar.php", {
            valorBusqueda: textoBusqueda1
        }, function(mensaje1) { // buscar.php es la pagina donde instanciaremos la clase y haremos la busqueda
            var total = porcentajequimico1 * mensaje1;
            $('#resultadoBusqueda2').val(total); //.val para ayadir valores de texto o variables a un input 
        });
    } else {

        $('#resultadoBusqueda2').val('escriba quimico'); // resultado busqueda es el contenedor donde mostramos el mensaje que es lo que hemos buscado con la palabra o nos aha devuelto la busqueda
    };
    // 3 busqueda de los input
    var textoBusqueda2 = $("input#busqueda3").val();
    if (textoBusqueda2 !== "") {
        $.post("buscar.php", {
            valorBusqueda: textoBusqueda2
        }, function(mensaje2) { // buscar.php es la pagina donde instanciaremos la clase y haremos la busqueda
            //$("#resultadoBusqueda").html(mensaje);// mensaje es el que se va a retornar al hacer la busqueda en la funcion de la clase claculadora
            $('#resultadoBusqueda3').val(mensaje2); //.val para ayadir valores de texto o variables a un input 
        });
    } else {

        $('#resultadoBusqueda3').val('escriba quimico'); // resultado busqueda es el contenedor donde mostramos el mensaje que es lo que hemos buscado con la palabra o nos aha devuelto la busqueda
    };
    // 3 busqueda de los input
    var textoBusqueda3 = $("input#busqueda4").val();
    if (textoBusqueda3 !== "") {
        $.post("buscar.php", {
            valorBusqueda: textoBusqueda3
        }, function(mensaje3) { // buscar.php es la pagina donde instanciaremos la clase y haremos la busqueda
            //$("#resultadoBusqueda").html(mensaje);// mensaje es el que se va a retornar al hacer la busqueda en la funcion de la clase claculadora
            $('#resultadoBusqueda4').val(mensaje3); //.val para ayadir valores de texto o variables a un input 
        });
    } else {

        $('#resultadoBusqueda4').val('escriba quimico'); // resultado busqueda es el contenedor donde mostramos el mensaje que es lo que hemos buscado con la palabra o nos aha devuelto la busqueda
    };
    // 3 busqueda de los input
    var textoBusqueda4 = $("input#busqueda5").val();
    if (textoBusqueda4 !== "") {
        $.post("buscar.php", {
            valorBusqueda: textoBusqueda4
        }, function(mensaje3) { // buscar.php es la pagina donde instanciaremos la clase y haremos la busqueda
            //$("#resultadoBusqueda").html(mensaje);// mensaje es el que se va a retornar al hacer la busqueda en la funcion de la clase claculadora
            $('#resultadoBusqueda5').val(mensaje3); //.val para ayadir valores de texto o variables a un input 
        });
    } else {

        $('#resultadoBusqueda5').val('escriba quimico'); // resultado busqueda es el contenedor donde mostramos el mensaje que es lo que hemos buscado con la palabra o nos aha devuelto la busqueda
    };
};
```

la cosa es que repito mucho todo y creo que se pudiera simplificar ademas necesito que se pase mediante un array la informacion optenida por el input con el id dinamico de los dos el de busqueda se pasaria por el y el del porcentaje quimico seria para multiplicar el valor devuelto por la consulta en la funcion con la variable mensaje commo se muestra y ademas mensaje deberia cambiar tambien pero eso es con la i del for

lo soluciones con esto

```
function buscar() {
var numeroinputs = $("input#numerobusqueda").val();
for (let i = 1; i <= numeroinputs; i++) {// creamos el for para meter las variables y hace un if que se ejecutara tantas veces como lo indique el numero de input en el for
```

let textoBusqueda = $("input#busqueda" + i).val();// cuando se ejecuten las vueltas del for pasaremos el id mas el valor de la 1 para hacer los id dinamicos y que se enparejen con los generados en php
  let porcentajequimico = $("input#porcentajequimico" + i).val();
    var arraybusqueda=[];
  if (textoBusqueda !== "" && porcentajequimico >= -1) {
      arraybusqueda.push(textoBusqueda);// cargamos en la variable array los valores dinamicos de palabras que ha dado el for con $("input#busqueda" + i).val();
      $.post("buscar.php", {// buscar.php es la pagina donde instanciaremos la clase y haremos la busqueda
          valorBusqueda: arraybusqueda// metemos el array que contendra dinamicamente todas las palabras en un array de cada busqueda de input
      }, function (mensaje) { // mensaje es el que se va a retornar al hacer la busqueda en la funcion de la clase claculadora
          var total = porcentajequimico * mensaje;// aqui calculamos el total de la densidad de un quimico
          $('#resultadoBusqueda' + i).val(total);// y hacemos el aadir al input
      });
  } else {
      $('#resultadoBusqueda' + i).val('escriba quimico'); 
  };
}

tuve que crear un variable de array

```
var arraybusqueda=[];
```

y despues hice un push del array dentro del if

```
arraybusqueda.push(textoBusqueda);// cargamos en la variable array los valores dinamicos de palabras que ha dado el for con $("input#busqueda" + i).val();
```

muchas gracias a ivan por su respuesta pongo lo que tube que modificar para que le pueda servir a alguien tambien

Comment: En lugar de usar ids podrias usar clases y un `for` o `each`

Comment: @alan si lo hago por el selector class la informacion se pondria en todos no solo en uno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seria mas facil usar un for? Tienes información igual donde solo cambian los numeros. Aprovechalo!

```js
for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
  let textoBusqueda = $("input#busqueda" + i).val();
  let porcentajequimico = $("input#porcentajequimico" + i).val();
  if (textoBusqueda !== "" && porcentajequimico !== 0) {
      $.post("buscar.php", {
          valorBusqueda: textoBusqueda
      }, function (mensaje) { 
          var total = porcentajequimico * mensaje;
          $('#resultadoBusqueda' + i).val(total);
      });
  } else {
      $('#resultadoBusqueda' + i).val('escriba quimico'); 
  };
}
```